# Sublime text: How to paste image into a markdown file?

Tags: sublime-text

In VS Code, we have a useful tool that can paste image on clipboard to our markdown file.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mushan.vscode-paste-image

In the paste,

an image file is created, and

a markdown link to the image is added into the file.

I have been looking for a similar tool in SublimeText but the closest is MarkdownEditing, which only creates an empty markdown link placeholder without creating the image file for me.

Is there a package that can create an image file from my clipboard?

I tried using imagepaste (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ImagePaste)

its not actively developed anymore (https://github.com/robinchenyu/imagepaste)

[image]

i tried it but its not working

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What is your OS?
I'm not familiar with sublime-text, but I know how to accomplish this goal in BASH.

```
sudo apt-get install xclip ImageMagick
```

This is the most simple form of how to output to image:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o | convert - output.png
```

---

There's an alternative to `pyscreenshot` called `Pillow`.

```
pip install Pillow
```

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab

# Grab the image from the clipboard
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

# Check if grab succeeded
if im:
    # Save the image
    im.save("/path/to/save/image.png")
else:
    # Print if the clipboard buffer is not an image
    print("Clipboard buffer is not an image.")
```

If I had more of an example of how you obtain this image, you might be able to incorporate `xclip`.

Hopefully `Pillow` will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a package called [ImagePaste](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ImagePaste) that might be what you need.

> For Linux
>
> `pip` install `PyUserInput`, `pyscreenshot` and install `python-pyqt4` as backend of `pyscreenshot`.

To make it work on Linux: replace `im = ImageGrab.getclipboard()` with `im = ImageGrab.grab()` in the `imageutil.py` file. [(1)](https://github.com/robinchenyu/imagepaste/issues/15#issuecomment-842393156)

Comment: its not much actively developed anymore https://github.com/robinchenyu/imagepaste